# Can't start Bind9 on Ubuntu 10.04 + Plesk 10.1 - "named: no process found"

Tags: ubuntu, bind

1. I've installed a fresh version of
   Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, I didn't install
   bind when choosing what packages
   should be installed in the Ubuntu
   installer.
2. I downloaded the auto installer for Plesk 10.1 and installed it successfully.
3. When I logged into the Plesk control panel and tried to change the password, it failed because it couldn't restart bind.

I SSH'd into the box and tried a `sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart` and get the following:

```
brad@ws01:/root# sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                                                                                                                                                WARNING: key file (/etc/bind/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/bind/rndc.conf)
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
named: no process found                                   [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                  [fail]
```

Looking at `tail /var/log/messages` reveals a whole bunch of:

```
Feb 23 16:08:21 ws01 kernel: [ 3840.065851] type=1503 audit(1298441301.831:31):  operation="open" pid=5565 parent=5563 profile="/usr/sbin/named" requested_mask="::r" denied_mask="::r" fsuid=108 ouid=0 name="/var/named/run-root/etc/named.conf"
```

**Edit:**

After following ooshro's advice, bind runs, however I still get the `named: no process found` error:

```
brad@ws01:/etc/apparmor.d$ sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9
WARNING: key file (/etc/bind/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/bind/rndc.conf)
named: no process found                    [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9   [ OK ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named:

```
/var/named/run-root/** rw,
```

Then restart AppArmor:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

Comment: Thanks ooshro, it is definitely behaving a little nicer, I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: @bradley.ayers If BIND not start, you need "/etc/init.d/bind9 start"... restart need if BIND start. Try restart BIND again.

Comment: Bind starts properly, it's just wierd that it complains about 'named'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reasons the previous process is still in memory.

Try to kill it manually

```
  ps -ef | grep named
```

You should get something like

```
  bind     13178     1  0 Feb17 ?        00:00:43 /usr/sbin/named -u bind
```

Then kill the process (replace 13178 with the PID you get)

```
  kill 13178
```

Try the `ps` again, if it doesn't die

```
  kill -9 13178
```

Then you can start bind again

```
  /etc/init.d/bind9 start
```